# How to open urllink.acsm file with Adobe Digital Editions when it's running with PlayOnLinux?

Tags: playonlinux, adobe

So to download ebooks from ebooks.com it requires Adobe Digital Editions, im using Ubuntu 20.04.2 and have successfully installed ADE. But because it's running with PlayOnLinux/WIne I can't directly open this file with ADE.

I have read i'm supposed to right click the downloaded ACSM file and open it with ADE, but this is installed on a virtual drive with PLayOnLinux so ADE isn't selectable from the desktop when I right click.

When I click 'add file to library' in ADE, it only looks for pdfs and epub files and not an acsm file...  Linux has been great except for trying to read a few books.

I'm new and just trying to learn. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set file association inside PlayOnLinux:

1. Open PlayOnLinux
2. Go to *Settings* → *File Associations*
3. Click *New*
4. Enter `acsm` in the opened window, click OK in it
5. Select `acsm` line in the table and set *Assigned program* to ADE executable
6. Click *Apply*
7. Restart PlayOnLinux
8. Try to open `acsm` file from file-manager by simple *Open*

---

Note: ACSM seems to be DRM format, so it will [not work](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#how-do-i-use-purchased-epub-books-with-calibre-or-what-do-i-do-with-acsm-files) with native Calibre application. So your rights are limited here.

Comment: Now I'm walking on water, thanks for the guidance.